# OpenGL - Can't get Vertex Array Objects and Vertex Buffer Objects to draw

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm using OpenGL with SDL2 on MacOSX 10.10. I've been trying to use VAOs and VBOs in modern OpenGL, but I am not able to get them to draw. My shaders are super simple, but according to tutorials I've been trying to follow they're supposed to work. I'm not getting any errors, but it's still not working. All I receive is a window that's completely black. If anyone could help me understand where my problem is and how I can fix it I would greatly appreciate it. I hope I'm not repeating a previous question, but I have searched and searched and found nothing to solve this problem. Here's my code:

vertexShader.glsl:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;

void main(){
    gl_Position.xyz = vertexPosition_modelspace;
    gl_Position.w = 1.0;
}
```

fragmentShader.glsl

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 color;

void main(){
    color = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Here is my code for loading the shaders, which has worked and provided no errors:

```
//Note: PXConsole is a util class for printing to the console.
GLuint loadShaders(std::string vertexPath, std::string fragmentPath){

const char* vertexShaderPath = vertexPath.c_str();
const char* fragmentShaderPath = fragmentPath.c_str();
// Create the shaders
GLuint VertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
GLuint FragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

// Read the Vertex Shader code from the file
std::string VertexShaderCode;
std::ifstream VertexShaderStream(vertexShaderPath, std::ios::in);
if(VertexShaderStream.is_open()){
    std::string Line = "";
    while(getline(VertexShaderStream, Line))
        VertexShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
    VertexShaderStream.close();
}else{
    std::string error ="Could not open vertex shader at \"" + vertexPath +"\". Is the the path written correctly? ";
    PXConsole::err(error);
    return 0;
}

// Read the Fragment Shader code from the file
std::string FragmentShaderCode;
std::ifstream FragmentShaderStream(fragmentShaderPath, std::ios::in);
if(FragmentShaderStream.is_open()){
    std::string Line = "";
    while(getline(FragmentShaderStream, Line))
        FragmentShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
    FragmentShaderStream.close();
}else{
    std::string error ="Could not open fragment shader at \"" + fragmentPath +"\". Is the the path written correctly? ";
    PXConsole::err(error);
    return 0;
}

GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
int InfoLogLength;


// Compile Vertex Shader
PXConsole::info("Compiling Vertex Shader at: " + vertexPath);
char const * VertexSourcePointer = VertexShaderCode.c_str();
glShaderSource(VertexShaderID, 1, &VertexSourcePointer , NULL);
glCompileShader(VertexShaderID);

// Check Vertex Shader
glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
if ( InfoLogLength > 0 ){
    std::vector<char> VertexShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength+1);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(VertexShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    PXConsole::err(&VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
}



// Compile Fragment Shader
PXConsole::info("Compiling Fragment Shader at: " + fragmentPath);
char const * FragmentSourcePointer = FragmentShaderCode.c_str();
glShaderSource(FragmentShaderID, 1, &FragmentSourcePointer , NULL);
glCompileShader(FragmentShaderID);

// Check Fragment Shader
glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
if ( InfoLogLength > 0 ){
    std::vector<char> FragmentShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength+1);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(FragmentShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    PXConsole::err(&FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
}



// Link the program
PXConsole::info("Linking Shader Program!");
GLuint ProgramID = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
glAttachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);
glLinkProgram(ProgramID);

// Check the program
glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Result);
glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
if ( InfoLogLength > 0 ){
    std::vector<char> ProgramErrorMessage(InfoLogLength+1);
    glGetProgramInfoLog(ProgramID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
    PXConsole::err(&ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
}


glDetachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
glDetachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);

glDeleteShader(VertexShaderID);
glDeleteShader(FragmentShaderID);

return ProgramID;
```

Here is my OpenGL context creation with SDL2:

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_FLAGS, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_FLAG);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);

appWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Window Title", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 1280, 720, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

if (!application->appWindow) {
    PXConsole::err("Couldn't Initialize Window!!");
    endApp();
}

appGLContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(appWindow);
```

And lastly here is my render function which is in a loop:

```
void render(){    

    GLuint vaoID;
    GLuint posVBO;

    GLfloat positions[] = {-0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f,
        -0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f};


    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //shaderProgramID = the function mentioned above in an initializating function and has no errors finding the shader files

    glUseProgram(shaderProgramID);

    glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoID);
    glBindVertexArray(vaoID);

    glGenBuffers(1, &posVBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, posVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(positions), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, posVBO);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glColor4f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(appWindow);
}
```

I hope that's enough code to be able to determine the issue. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A VAO basically stores the attribute bindings set by `glVertexAttribPointer`. In order to store them, they have to be set while the VAO is bound. In your case, you first unbind it and then set the attribute binding.

Additionally, one should **never** generate buffers or vaos in each frame. This are things that have to be done during initialization.

Since you said in the question that you are not getting any errors: There are at least three of them in each frame. How do you check for errors?

- `glColor4f` has been removed from the OpenGL 3.3 Core Profile. Calling this should result in an error. (2x)
- `GL_QUADS` is not a valid [drawing mode](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml) in Core Profile and should also generate an error.

A corrected version could look like this

*Init*

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoID);
glBindVertexArray(vaoID);

glGenBuffers(1, &posVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, posVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(positions), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

*Render*

```
glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

**Update**

When you want to use new coordinates in each frame, you still generate the buffers and setup the VAO in the initialization. What you do in each frame is to upload new data to the buffer like this (assuming the amount of vertices stays the same):

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, posVBO);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(positions), positions);
```

This will override the data of the buffer without allocating new GPU memory. Note that you have to call `glBufferData` once in the initialization with the correct size, but with a nullptr as data pointer to allocate the memory for the buffer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and advice! I'm newer to using OpenGL in the right way. The reason I generated the buffer in the each frame was because I'm used to changing the position of the object to make it move, rather than using an OpenGL camera. I don't think I'm checking for OpenGL errors. How should I go about that? And you're solution almost worked perfectly, except calling glDisableVertexAttribArray(0) only allowed the shape to appear for a frame and then dissapeared. Should I just call this when the program is closing? But really, thanks again for the help and advice!

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry. That one slipped through. You don't have to called that. That's only relevant when not using VAOs. When closing the problem this is done for you in the `glDeleteVertexArray` method.

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough help! I greatly appreciate it.